# TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable simulator

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a simulation for DTN network the idea is to read a file with 3 elements each one represents time, source address, and destination address. The problem is that with this code that I have so far I get an error message. I don't know anything about python or any other coding program I'm just following tutorials.

```
import xlsxwriter as xlwt

#xbook = xlwt.Workbook("Test.xlsx")
#xsheet1 = xbook.add_worksheet("singlehop")

base_time =  1390911881273
M = []

def epidemic(_sa, _da):
    global base_time, M
    M = set([_sa])
    for line in open("C:/simulator/new_contact.txt").readlines():
        t, sa, da = line.strip().split()

        if sa in M:
            M.add(da)
            if _da in M:
                return (float(t) - base_time)/1000.0

t = epidemic(1, 10)
print (M)                 
#                  xsheet1.write(a, 0, sa)
#                  xsheet1.write(a, 1, da)
#                  xsheet1.write(a, 2, t)

#xbook.close()
```

Thanks to your help guys now I don't have the iterate problem anymore. However, the result of this code gives me M = {1}, It's not adding the hops from 1 to 10 to M.

Comment: `M = (sa)` is equivalent to `M = sa`. To create a singleton tuple, use `M = (sa,)`. However, there's not much point in wrapping a single value in a tuple just to check if a value is equal to that single item; `if _da == sa` is the same. (Did you intend to modify `M` during the loop? In that case, you need to use a list anyway.)

Comment: Related, `m` is not defined anywhere; is that supposed to be `M`?

Comment: yes my intention is to append to M all the sa and da of the simulation since is a message that should go from A to D i need B and C to be in M. The problem with a list is that I might have repeated elements and i just want one of them to be shown in M

Comment: A tuple could have repeated elements as well, and is immutable, so you couldn't add *anything* to it anyway. You probably want `M = set([_sa])`, then `if sa in M: M.add(da)`.

Comment: I did what you suggested changing   M = set([_sa]) it worked but why is that I'm getting now    M = {1}, the code is not inserting anything on M but 1

Comment: Solved, thanks @chepner

Answer (score 1):

As the error message shows you the error is in line 17, so let's check this line.

```
if sa in M:
    m.append(da)
```

The message says that an integer is not iterable and you want to iterate over M. So could M be an integer?

Let's look at the point where M changes the value the last time.

```
M = (_sa)
```

The parenthesis dont make a different in python if you use this brackets [] you get a list, so maybe this is the mistake? _sa is the parameter given to this function and this is indeed an integer and this is not iterable.

Answer (score 0):

First can you put the link to the tutorial?
Second I see a couple of mistakes:
1) m.append(da) will not work because you did not declare m
2) M = (_sa) is an integer not a collection

From what I can see, M get 1 as integer (which is not iterable), but the code will fail when it hits m.append(da) anyway.

Comment: Well there is no tutorial for the overall code i just followed different tutorials to build this code. I already changed m.append(da) to M.append(da) i just noticed that. In any case how can i modify M = () if an integer can not be iterate?

Comment: @DanielHernandez What do you expect by iterating over an integer?

Comment: @DanielHernandez the problem is that this error are related to know basic python you should do some beginners tutorial of python. It is more complicated that just change M declaration.

Comment: I just expect to see how many jumps I have from the source to destination I have no idea what is iterate or anything related to python. I started like a week ago with the "Hello World!" tutorial and now i don't know how to keep going with this simulator. I'm a network engineer not a computer science engineer. Unfortunately, my project advisor wants me to do this on python, otherwise i would be using one of the network software that are already out there.